# PBI Report Builder X-Axis values cutoff

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, reportbuilder3.0

Hi I'm using PBI Report Builder.  When I run my report in normal view, I can see my year on the x-axis, but I need to print the report to PDF, so when I look at it in 'Print Layout' mode, the x-axis labels visually get cutoff (also when I print to pdf as well).  I've tried playing around with the chart properties but I can't really find how to get the print layout to mimic the default view.  Increasing the size of the charts doesn't seem to do anything either.

default view (category axis looks correct)
[image: default view]

print layout view (notice the category axis gets cutoff on all 3 charts)
[image: page view]

Comment: check your report size properties, body size properties and the page size properties. As long as the body size is less than the report minus margins, and the report is less than the page minus its margins then it should be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to follow up with an answer in case anyone else runs into this bug.

I don't think it had anything to do with my margins/body/page size.  For some reason Report Builder just likes to cutoff the x-axis in page layout.  When generating/exporting the PDF from a Power Automate flow using the PBI Paginated Report activity, it renders all the x-axis labels properly.